# User preferences file vs App preferences file

Tags: xml, android, preferences, shared, sharedpreferences

My android application has two kinds of preferences:

1) I have **user preferences** defined in res/xml/preferences.xml so that users can manage their preferences with a PreferenceActivity.

2) I'd like to define another file for global **configuration preferences** of my app.

What is the best way to manage my app config preferences? Should I create another XML file with config values or should I specify those config values in strings.xml? What is the best practice for managing config preferences?

Answer (score 6):

Preference files are **not** storead in project's `/res/xml/defaults.xml`

They are stored on the device in your application folder something like

```
/data/data/com.your.pkg/default.prefs
```

Try do not specify the file name, as you will have some problems with the preference files, like this OP had in this question: [How do I get preferences to work in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011604/how-do-i-get-preferences-to-work-in-android)

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

Then you will probably have to query

```
preferences.getString('weightPref', null);
```

Many applications may provide a way to capture user preferences on the settings of a specific application or an activity. For supporting this, Android provides a simple set of APIs.

Preferences are typically name value pairs. They can be stored as “Shared Preferences” across various activities in an application (note currently it cannot be shared across processes). Or it can be something that needs to be stored specific to an activity.

1. Shared Preferences: The shared preferences can be used by all the components (activities, services etc) off the applications.
2. Activity handled preferences: These preferences can only be used with in the activity and can not be used by other components of the application.

**Shared Preferences:**

The shared preferences are managed with the help of `getSharedPreferences` method of the `Context` class. The preferences are stored in a default file(1) or you can specify a file name(2) to be used to refer to the preferences.

(1) Here is how you get the instance when you specify the file name

```
public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "PrefFile";
   SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

`MODE_PRIVATE` is the operating mode for the preferences. It is the default mode and means the created file will be accessed by only the calling application.  Other two mode supported are `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` and `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE`. In `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` other application can read the created file but can not modify it. In case of `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE` other applications also have write permissions for the created file.

(2) **The recommended way** is to use by the default mode, without specifying the file name

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferencesManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

Finally, once you have the preferences instance, here is how you can **retrieve the stored values** from the preferences:

```
 int storedPreference = preferences.getInt("storedInt", 0);
```

To **store values** in the preference file `SharedPreference.Editor` object has to be used. `Editor` is the nested interface of the `SharedPreference` class.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putInt("storedInt", storedPreference); // value to store
editor.commit();
```

Editor also support methods like `remove()` and `clear()` to delete the preference value from the file.

**Activity Preferences:**

The shared preferences can be used by other application components. But if you do not need to share the preferences with other components and want to have activities private preferences. You can do that with the help of `getPreferences()` method of the activity. The `getPreference` method uses the `getSharedPreferences()` method with the name of the activity class for the preference file name.

Following is the code to get preferences

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
int storedPreference = preferences.getInt("storedInt", 0);
```

The code to store values is also same as in case of shared preferences.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreference(MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putInt("storedInt", storedPreference); // value to store
editor.commit();
```

You can also use other methods like storing the activity state in database. Note Android  also contains a package called `android.preference`. The package defines classes to implement application preferences UI.

To see some more examples check Android's [Data Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011604/how-do-i-get-preferences-to-work-in-android) post on developers site.

Comment: Please [don't use "here" or "click here" as link text](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere.html). Thanks!

Comment: What I want to do is for one side to define a user preferences xml file with default values in res/xml/preferences.xml, as you mentioned I can get these preferences with:

PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

On the other side I want to define in another file another kind of preferences for configuring my app (users cannot manage these config preferences, only the code of my app will be able to read them). My question is where can I specify the default values for these config preferences, if I already have a file for user preferences (res/xml/preferences.xml).

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that your xml reads like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <CheckBoxPreference android:key="gpsOn" 
                    android:summaryOff="GPS is Off"
                    android:summaryOn="GPS is On" 
                    android:title="GPS State"></CheckBoxPreference>
```

I assume you use a `PreferenceActivity` to load the preferences from your xml. So in your activity you do `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.application_pref);`

When you do this, by default, all the values are stored in the default SharedPreference of the application. You can access these preferences in anywhere you want. So from some other activity/service just do:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
boolean value = prefs.getBoolean("gpsOn", false);
```

And just like that you should get the user's preference in `value`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to set **global configuration** preferences for an app is to define meta-data elements in the Android Manifest