# Serializing a SparseArray<T> with GSON

Tags: android, serialization, sharedpreferences, gson

I want to serialize a custom Java object, so I can use `SharedPreferences` to store it and retreive it in another Activity. I don't need persistant storage, the `SharedPreferences`, I  wipe them when my application is closed. I'm currently using GSON for this, but it doesn't seem to work well with Android's SparseArray type.

My objects:

```
public class PartProfile {

private int gameId;
// Some more primitives
private SparseArray<Part> installedParts = new SparseArray<Part>();

// ...
}

public class Part {
   private String partName;
   // More primitives
}
```

Serialization:

```
Type genericType = new TypeToken<PartProfile>() {}.getType();
String serializedProfile = Helpers.serializeWithJSON(installedParts, genericType);
preferences.edit().putString("Parts", serializedProfile).commit();
```

serializeWithJSON():

```
public static String serializeWithJSON(Object o, Type genericType) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.toJson(o, genericType);
}
```

Deserialization:

```
Type genericType = new TypeToken<PartProfile>() {}.getType();
PartProfile parts = gson.fromJson(preferences.getString("Parts", "PARTS_ERROR"), genericType);

SparseArray<Part> retreivedParts = parts.getInstalledParts();
int key;
for (int i = 0; i < retreivedParts.size(); i++) {
    key = retreivedParts.keyAt(i);
    // Exception here:
    Part part = retreivedParts.get(key);
    // ...
}
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.mypackage.objects.Part
```

I don't understand why Gson wants to cast a `LinkedTreeMap` to my object, I never use one in my entire program. I used to have a `HashMap<Integer,Part>` before I switched to the `SparseArray<Part>`, and never had issues with that. Are SparseArrays not supported by Gson, or is there an error on my side?

Edit: It seems that the SparseArray gets deserialized correctly, but not the objects inside. Instead of `LinkedTreeMaps`, these should be of type `Part`.[image]

Comment: `SharedPreferences` persist across sessions (even if the application is killed). Read [Using Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Comment: Yeah, but I wipe them manually with clear(). I just wanted to point out that persisting them isn't necessary.

Comment: `SharedPreferences` are not meant for sharing data across activities. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/q/3549596/1321873 for more info.

Comment: See if preserving typing information solves your issue: http://pragmateek.com/javajson-mapping-with-gson/#Preserving_type_information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It seems that the SparseArray gets deserialized correctly, but not the
>   objects inside. Instead of LinkedTreeMaps, these should be of type
>   Part.

Your observation is correct, since **SparseArray contains Object** (not `Part`), Gson won't have any clue to make Part as your object type. Hence it map your list as its infamous internal type `LinkedTreeMap`.

To solve it, I think you won't be able to use `SparseArray`... Or you may try `retreivedParts.get(key).toString()`, then use gson to parse the object again. But I don't think it's efficient to do that

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer, since there doesn't seem a proper solution to that. I replaced my SparseArrays with HashMaps, but I had to use `Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().enableComplexMapKeySerialization().create()` to serialize them, since somehow my custom objects weren't properly deserialized without that option enabled.

Answer (score 13):

Really there is a way to serialize any kind of `SparseArray`, here is an example code:

```java
public class SparseArrayTypeAdapter<T> extends TypeAdapter<SparseArray<T>> {

    private final Gson gson = new Gson();
    private final Class<T> classOfT;
    private final Type typeOfSparseArrayOfT = new TypeToken<SparseArray<T>>() {}.getType();
    private final Type typeOfSparseArrayOfObject = new TypeToken<SparseArray<Object>>() {}.getType();

    public SparseArrayTypeAdapter(Class<T> classOfT) {
        this.classOfT = classOfT;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter jsonWriter, SparseArray<T> tSparseArray) throws IOException {
        if (tSparseArray == null) {
            jsonWriter.nullValue();
            return;
        }
        gson.toJson(gson.toJsonTree(tSparseArray, typeOfSparseArrayOfT), jsonWriter);
    }

    @Override
    public SparseArray<T> read(JsonReader jsonReader) throws IOException {
        if (jsonReader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
            jsonReader.nextNull();
            return null;
        }
        SparseArray<Object> temp = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, typeOfSparseArrayOfObject);
        SparseArray<T> result = new SparseArray<T>(temp.size());
        int key;
        JsonElement tElement;
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
            key = temp.keyAt(i);
            tElement = gson.toJsonTree(temp.get(key));
            result.put(key, gson.fromJson(tElement, classOfT));
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

and to use it you need to register it in your `Gson` object, like this:

```java
Type sparseArrayType = new TypeToken<SparseArray<MyCustomClass>>() {}.getType();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(sparseArrayType, new SparseArrayTypeAdapter<MyCustomClass>(MyCustomClass.class))
    .create();
```

you can find this example in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/dmarcato/6455221).

P.S.: I know it's not optimized at all, but it's only an example to give an idea on how to achieve what you need.

Comment: This code works. However, I still do not use it as solution as SparseArray is not Parcable/Serializable. Hence, it is pretty difficult for me to pass it around to different activities and processes. End up, I fall back to HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the other answers `SparseArray`'s [internal implementation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/a5d1ef9837455129b91df4a37ae72e59644d04c2/core/java/android/util/SparseArray.java#63) uses an `Object[]` to store the values so Gson cannot deserialize it correctly.

This can be solved by creating a custom Gson [`TypeAdapterFactory`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.6/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory.html):

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

import android.util.SparseArray;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;

public class SparseArrayTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
    public static final SparseArrayTypeAdapterFactory INSTANCE = new SparseArrayTypeAdapterFactory();
    
    private SparseArrayTypeAdapterFactory() { }
    
    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
        // This factory only supports (de-)serializing SparseArray
        if (type.getRawType() != SparseArray.class) {
            return null;
        }
        
        // Get the type argument for the element type parameter `<E>`
        // Note: Does not support raw SparseArray type (i.e. without type argument)
        Type elementType = ((ParameterizedType) type.getType()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        TypeAdapter<?> elementAdapter = gson.getAdapter(TypeToken.get(elementType));
        
        // This is safe because check at the beginning made sure type is SparseArray
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        TypeAdapter<T> adapter = (TypeAdapter<T>) new SparseArrayTypeAdapter<>(elementAdapter);
        // call nullSafe() to make adapter automatically handle `null` SparseArrays
        return adapter.nullSafe();
    }
    
    private static class SparseArrayTypeAdapter<E> extends TypeAdapter<SparseArray<E>> {
        private final TypeAdapter<E> elementTypeAdapter;
        
        public SparseArrayTypeAdapter(TypeAdapter<E> elementTypeAdapter) {
            this.elementTypeAdapter = elementTypeAdapter;
        }
        
        @Override
        public void write(JsonWriter out, SparseArray<E> sparseArray) throws IOException {
            out.beginObject();
            
            int size = sparseArray.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                out.name(Integer.toString(sparseArray.keyAt(i)));
                elementTypeAdapter.write(out, sparseArray.valueAt(i));
            }
            
            out.endObject();
        }

        @Override
        public SparseArray<E> read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
            in.beginObject();
            
            SparseArray<E> sparseArray = new SparseArray<>();
            while (in.hasNext()) {
                int key = Integer.parseInt(in.nextName());
                E value = elementTypeAdapter.read(in);
                // Use `append(...)` here because SparseArray is serialized in ascending
                // key order so `key` will be > previously added key
                sparseArray.append(key, value);
            }
            
            in.endObject();
            return sparseArray;
        }
        
    }
}
```

This factory serializes SparseArrays as JSON objects with the key as JSON property name and the value serialized with the respective adapter as JSON value, e.g.:

```
new SparseArray<List<String>>().put(5, Arrays.asList("Hello", "World"))
```

↓ JSON

```
{"5": ["Hello", "World"]}
```

You then use this TypeAdapterFactory by creating your Gson instance using a `GsonBuilder` on which you [register](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.6/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#registerTypeAdapterFactory(com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory)) the TypeAdapterFactory:

```java
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapterFactory​(SparseArrayTypeAdapterFactory.INSTANCE)
    .create();
```