# GSON deserialize an array of complex objects

Tags: java, gson, arrays

I want to deserialize an array of complex objects

for instance i have object `MyTestObject`

```
public class MyTestObject{

    String param1;
    String param2; 
    int param3;
}
```

now i have an array of objects named `MyTestObject`

and my json looks like this

```
{
[
"param1":"something1",
"param2:"something2",
"param3":3
],
[
"param1":"something1",
"param2:"something2",
"param3":3
],
[
"param1":"something1",
"param2:"something2",
"param3":3
]
}
```

this is my code for desearilization

```
public static <T> List<T> fromJSON(String json, Class<T> className) {
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.serializeNulls();
    Type myType = new TypeToken<List<T>>() {
    }.getType();
    Gson g1 = builder.create();
    List<T> objects = (List<T>) g1.fromJson(json, (Type) myType);
    for (T object : objects) {
        Log.d(TAG, "object: " + object + " class " + object.getClass());
    }
    return objects;
}

ArrayList<MyTestObject> objects = fromJSON(myjson,MyTestObject.class);
```

the array itself gets deserialized correctly, however, the objects inside it are not of the correct class, they are of type `com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap`

when i need them to be of type `MyTestObject`

how do i fix this?

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17231298/serializing-a-sparsearrayt-with-gson

Comment: That's not valid JSON! You can't have this `{[...], [...], [...]}`, but you need this `{'foo':[...], 'bar':[...], 'baz':[...]}`... I mean, the arrays within the root object must have a name...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sample :

```
public class Test<T> {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new Test<String>().test(String.class);
    new Test<Integer>().test(Integer.class);
    new Test<Long>().test(Long.class);
  }

  public void test(Class<T> cls) throws Exception {
    TypeToken<?> typeOfT = getGenToken(List.class, cls);
    List<?> lst = (List<?>) new Gson().fromJson("[1, 2, 3]", typeOfT.getType());

    for (Object o : lst) {
      System.out.println("value : " + o + ", type : " + o.getClass());
    }
  }

  static TypeToken<?> getGenToken(final Class<?> raw, final Class<?> gen) throws Exception {
    Constructor<ParameterizedTypeImpl> constr = ParameterizedTypeImpl.class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.class, Type[].class, Type.class);
    constr.setAccessible(true);
    ParameterizedTypeImpl paramType = constr.newInstance(raw, new Type[] { gen }, null);

    return TypeToken.get(paramType);
  }
}
```

`ParameterizedTypeImpl` came from `sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl`.

Output :

```
value : 1, type : class java.lang.String
value : 2, type : class java.lang.String
value : 3, type : class java.lang.String
value : 1, type : class java.lang.Integer
value : 2, type : class java.lang.Integer
value : 3, type : class java.lang.Integer
value : 1, type : class java.lang.Long
value : 2, type : class java.lang.Long
value : 3, type : class java.lang.Long
```

Note : in fact we could replace the wildcar with `T`, but that's not usefull here.

Comment: hm, android does not have Oracle JVM functions, do you have a different way to do `ParameterizedTypeImpl` ?

Comment: you can try to make your own implementation of `ParameterizedTypeImpl`, simply copy/paste the code of the Sun class, you can google the source easily

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `new TypeToken<List<T>>()`, because of type erasure GSon won't know the type of `T`.
https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Generic-Types

You can either provide in a static way `T`like

```
Type myType = new TypeToken<List<Something>>() {
}.getType();
```

Or build a `TypeToken` with a `Class<T>` var for the generic. There is no simple way to do this as far as I know. This is how I do it :

```
 static TypeToken<?> getGenToken(final Class<?> raw, final Class<?> gen) throws Exception {
    Constructor<ParameterizedTypeImpl> constr = ParameterizedTypeImpl.class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.class, Type[].class, Type.class);
    constr.setAccessible(true);
    ParameterizedTypeImpl paramType = constr.newInstance(raw, new Type[] { gen }, null);

    return TypeToken.get(paramType);
  }
```

Then you can build the token like this :

```
Class<T> tClass = ...;
Type myType = new getGenToken<List.class, tClass>()
```

Comment: I get noSuchMethodException for that on the getDeclaredConstructor

Comment: Strange. Which Gson version ? What constructor(s) do you see ? `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ParameterizedTypeImpl.class.getDeclaredConstructors()));`

Comment: Also the method I provided simply allow to return an instance of a `ParameterizedType`. If you want you can extract `ParameterizedTypeImpl` (which is static private final) located in `$Gson$Types` and make it public.

Comment: can you give me a working example please? i am battling with this for 2 days now , i have a josn arry filled with json objects all of the same type, if i deserialize each object individually, they are fine, if i try to extract them from the array... there goes the problem, strangely enough, there is a json array as one of the parameters in the object, that is of a difference class, and it gets deserialized just fine, this is why i thought this may work too, but i don't understand why it doesnt