# How to parse String List<Object> into List<GenericType> using Gson

Tags: list, double, gson, generic-type-argument

I wanna build a Class to parse `List<T>` to/from `String` using Gson:

```
private static class ListParser<T> {

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    public Type getGenericClass() {
        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<T>>() {
        }.getType();
        return listType;
    }

    public String toJson(List<T> list) {
        return gson.toJson(list, getGenericClass());
    }

    public List<T> fromJson(String json) {
        List<T> list1 = gson.fromJson(json, getGenericClass());
        List<T> list2 = new ArrayList<T>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
            T val = (T) list1.get(i);
            list2.add(val);
        }
        return list2;
    }
}
```

I used `TypeToken` as some tutorial I've found, but `list1` and `list2` were all `List<Double>`. I wonder if there is anyway to parse `List<Double>` to `List<T>` in Java.

Comment: I do not understand the question, your class is parametrized by T, so it will parse any list of T if JSON string in appropriate. By the way, you do now need two List in `fromJson` but just `List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>(); list = gson.fromJson(json, getGenericType);`

Answer (score 0):

Your `getGenericClass()` won't work, you need to retrieve the class of T.

You can provide it :

```
  Class<T> type;

  public Class<T> getType() {
    return this.type;
  }
```

or get it at runtime (unsafe, you can find many post on this subjet I think)

```
  public Class<T> getType() {
    return (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
  }
```

Then to build the list token you can use this code :

```
  static TypeToken<?> getGenToken(final Class<?> raw, final Class<?> gen) throws Exception {
    Constructor<ParameterizedTypeImpl> constr = ParameterizedTypeImpl.class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.class, Type[].class, Type.class);
    constr.setAccessible(true);
    ParameterizedTypeImpl paramType = constr.newInstance(raw, new Type[] { gen }, null);

    return TypeToken.get(paramType);
  }
```

Check the sample I provided here : [GSON deserialize an array of complex objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055041/gson-deserialize-an-array-of-complex-objects/18065753#18065753)