# Sharing data between an activity and a class

Tags: android

I have an activity `MyActivity` that holds a service class `MyService`.
I would like the service to send `String` data to the activity, and then create a `button` using this data.
Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3551010/1869297) post I created a `static` method in the activity.
The problem of course is that i can't use `this` in a static context.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {


    private MyService myService;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        myService = new MyService();

    }


    public static void connectMethod (String buttonName) {

        Button btn = new Button(this); // error
        btn.setId(i);
        final int buttonID = btn.getId();
        btn.setText(buttonName + buttonID);

    }
}





public class MyService {

    ...

    private void showButton (String data) {
        MyActivity.connectedMethod(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: read about "bound services" in android os

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible solutions to avoid your `error`:

1. ```
   public static void connectMethod (Context context, String buttonName) {

       Button btn = new Button(context); 
       btn.setId(i);
       final int buttonID = btn.getId();
       btn.setText(buttonName + buttonID);

   }

   // ...

   public class MyService {

       private Context context;

       public MyService(Context context) {
           this.context = context;
       }
       ...

       private void showButton (String data) {
           MyActivity.connectedMethod(context, data);
       }
    }
   ```
2. Or create a static class field : `private static Context context;`

   ```
   public static void connectMethod (String buttonName) {

       Button btn = new Button(context); 
       btn.setId(i);
       final int buttonID = btn.getId();
       btn.setText(buttonName + buttonID);

   }
   ```