# Is sychronization required when sharing data between Activity and Service?

Tags: android, multithreading, synchronization

I've been reading about how to share data between an Activity and a Service.  I found some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549596/sharing-data-amongst-activities-and-services) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/android-whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities).  I'm planning on creating a singleton class as this seems like the lowest overhead mechanism to share state.

For my application, I have a service which is acquiring and logging various sensor data and is filling a data structure with the most current state, and then notifying the activity to update the UI with this info, if the activity is visible.  If the activity is not visible, then when it becomes visible it consults the state information to update the UI.

I don't see any mention of whether synchronization is necessary.  For instance, isn't it possible that the UI thread might be pulling data out of the structure and get interrupted by the service which then puts new data in, resulting in the UI being rendered incorrectly?  Also, I want to put a flag on various pieces of data so the front end knows which pieces have been updated: the service would set a boolean and the activity would clear it.  It seems like a similar problem could occur here.

Do I need to worry about this, or is it impossible for the UI thread in the activity and the (e.g.) Listener or Receiver thread in the service to interrupt each other.  If they can, is it sufficient to use synchronized methods to access the data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For instance, isn't it possible that the UI thread might be pulling data out of the structure and get interrupted by the service which then puts new data in, resulting in the UI being rendered incorrectly?

Possibly. A `Service` usually has background threads, whether you create them or you get them from specific `Service` implementations (e.g., the thread used by `IntentService` for `onHandleIntent()`). Synchronization is not an issue of *components* (activities, services, etc.), but rather an issue of *threads*.

> If they can, is it sufficient to use synchronized methods to access the data structure?

Well, personally, I try to use synchronized objects and collections from `java.util.concurrent` and `java.util.concurrent.atomic`. Depending on what you're doing and how you're doing it, `synchronized` methods may be a fine solution.