# How to retrieve shared preferences into a non-activity class from an activity class in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I have a value in an activity class. I want to use that value in a non activity class. Normally, to share data between activity classes, I use like,

**FirstActivityClass.java**

```
SharedPreferences notification_id = getSharedPreferences("NOTIFICATION_ID", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor notificationIDEditor = notification_id.edit();
notificationIDEditor.putString("notification_id", notificationId)                
notificationIDEditor.apply();
```

And to retrieve the value of notification_id in another class,

**SecondActivityClass.java**

```
SharedPreferences notificationIDSharedRetrieve = getSharedPreferences("NOTIFICATION_ID", MODE_PRIVATE);
notificationID = notificationIDSharedRetrieve .getString("notification_id", null);
```

But suppose the second class was a non-activity class, how can I retrieve the data in a non-activity class?

Comment: if `second class was a non-activity class` then pass Context to second class for accessing `getSharedPreferences ` method

Comment: Some syntax, or knowledge about methodology for this, would help.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549596/sharing-data-amongst-activities-and-services) helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can send your Activity context to your calss by creating a custom constructor for example:

```
class A
{
Context con;
public A(Context con)
    {
    this.con=con
    }
}



Activity B
{
Context con;
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         this.con=getContext();
         A = new A(this.con);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cache the global Application context.

```
myApplicationContext.getSharedPreferences(NOTIFICATION_ID", MODE_PRIVATE)
```