# Are SharedPreferences stored in databases?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Is this correct?

SharedPreferences are stored in databases?

Comment: may be its off topic but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572780/android-sharedpreference) might help you.

Comment: @Harry Joy it is not off-topic, he/she is having confusion regarding the storage place of sharedpreferences.

Comment: @Paresh: may be possible its not off topic but i am not sure if he finds his answer on that site thats why written like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am agreed with @Octavian answer (up voted), it is stored inside the file.

> SharedPreferrences are stored in
>   databases?

**As i have written answer, NO, its stores inside the file inside your project directory.**

To view this file, go to **DDMS Perspective**, click on the **File Explorer**.
From File Explorer, **`data -> data -> your project -> shared_prefs`**.

Above, shared_prefs is the folder contains all the shared preferences you have declared and used.

Comment: **+1 - it's nice and helpful**

Answer (score 3):

No it is not correct. `SharedPreferences` are stored as XML files in your applications directory.

Answer (score -2):

Actually shared preferences store value into a variable .it is saved as like key-value pair

below is the code is used for store and retrieve values through shared preference values.

```
SharedPreferences prefs=getSharedPreferences("Key", 0);
          Editor e=  prefs.edit();
           e.putString("Name", "AAA");
           e.commit();
```

For retrieve the shared prefs value use below code

```
SharedPreferences prefs=getSharedPreferences("Key", 0);
          String s= prefs.getString("Name", "");
```

Comment: The question was how are the preferences stored on disk, not how you read/write them.