# How to store and read an integer in Internal Storage

Tags: android, int, storage, internal

I have been spending the last few hours researching on how to store data within internal storage however I cannot for some reason be capable of storing an integer.

I would like to know how to store an int value within a file as well as be able to read off of it.
Please provide a brief example on how I can achieve this and would it be preferable to use the SharedPreferences class?

Comment: If you are considering to save one value, it is much advisable to use SharedPreferences than file handling.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572780/android-sharedpreference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) if it is just an int value:

```
public int getValue() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    return prefs.getInt("value_key", 0);
}

public void setValue(int newValue) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("value_key", newValue);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked perfectly.

Comment: One more thing; I want to check if the file exists, how would I use the .exist() method with this code?

Comment: You mean you want to check if there is a value before you put one?

Comment: When the activity runs, I wish it to check if the file was created. If it exists, it will read it, otherwise it will create the file. Would I just use an if statement seeking if the value == 0?

I wish for it to read the file before it overwrites the file.

Comment: Yes. if `prefs.getInt()` returns `0` this means there is no value with a key `value_key`. You can put `-1` instead of `0` if you want.

Comment: I appreciate your help very much! :)

Comment: @ChallengeAccepted Any time :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes I think `SharedPreferences` would be the easiest way :

```
SharedPrefrences prefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
Editor editor=prefs.edit();
editor.putInt("MYINT",intValue);
editor.commit();
```

To retrieve the `int` use :

```
PreferenceManger.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getInt("MYINT",-1);
```