# How to have splash screen at first launch only?

Tags: android, android-intent, splash-screen

I have a splash activity in my app that launches and then loads the main class after 5 seconds. I'm thinking of changing it to where the splash only displays on the initial launch of the app. I was thinking of just writing a text file to the filesystem and then checking to see if its there. If its found, then dont load the splash screen. Is there a better way of doing a check to see if the app is on the first launch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of that you can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) because its easy to implement, fetch and take values from it as compared to file system.

Refer this question for the example of SharedPreference: [Android-sharedpreference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572780/android-sharedpreference)

Comment: Thanks! I believe I will give that a go! Looks like the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SharedPreference to save Simple String that represents your Splash screen.